# record audio in HTML / js without Flash?

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

Record audio from microphone and ajax post back to server?

Really dunno how to do it in flash, and want it keep simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At present, no browser implements [the WHATWG device API](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#devices), so you can't do this with just HTML, JavaScript and APIs provided by the browser.

If you want to do this, you need to use a plugin, and Flash is the most widespread plugin that will do what you want.

A Java applet would probably come next, but I suspect you'll find it more complex than using Flash.

Answer (score 1):

The Mozilla Rainbow plugin supports recording audio in Firefox without the need for flash.  It is still in heavy development though.

Answer (score -2):

[jquery Media](http://jquery.malsup.com/media/)

this is a usefull link to add media to your webpage using jquery

Comment: OP wants to RECORD not just embed and play media