# Record audio in HTML

Tags: web-audio-api

I am trying to figure out how to record audio in a web application but couldn't find anything. Is there really no way still?

I am particularly interested in an API that works on mobile.

Ref: [record audio in HTML / js without Flash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710683/record-audio-in-html-js-without-flash)

Comment: Look here:  https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's the Recorder.js library that William mentioned in the comment above (https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs), and then there's a new API being implemented called the Media Recorder API (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder_API) that has less support at the moment, but is a standard as opposed to a third party library.

Answer (score -1):

Only thing that I found so far was this. Take a look at it.

https://github.com/CreateJS/SoundJS